# How mock PropertyValidatorContext for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

How can I mock the PropertyValidatorContext class in unit test? Tech stack: C# .Net Core 3.1

For example to test the Foo method:

```
public async Task<bool> Foo(PropertyValidatorContext context) {...}
```

I currently used null as the input of foo `Foo(null)` but I am looking for a more elegant way if possible.

Here is the definition of PropertyValidatorContext:

```
namespace FluentValidation.Validators
{
    public class PropertyValidatorContext : IValidationContext
    {
        public PropertyValidatorContext(ValidationContext parentContext, PropertyRule rule, string propertyName);
        public PropertyValidatorContext(ValidationContext parentContext, PropertyRule rule, string propertyName, object propertyValue);
```

Please explain your solution at the beginner level.
Thank you